# Split each element of Array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, split

I have a 1D array with a bunch of text (Names) in each element. I would like to split each element using the Delimiter " | "

```
Dim AllAssignees() As String
'Import the three Assignee Columns to AllAssignees Array
AllAssignees = GetArrayFromColumns("Rawdata", 2, "I", "J", "K") 

Dim temparr() As String

For a = 0 To UBound(AllAssignees)
    Proof = InStr(1, AllAssignees(a), " | ")
    Select Case Proof
        Case Is <> "0"
            temparr = Split(AllAssignees(a), " | ")
    End Select
Next a
```

This is my code, which doesn't work. It only recognizes one element and splits it and I get a temparr with only two elements.

Is there another way to tackle this problem?

Comment: I think the problem might be that you are overwriting temparr in each iteration. https://medium.com/@breakcorporate/vba-add-items-to-an-array-942e3431c159
Try adding elements to the array instead

Comment: Could you give an example of the data you have?  Your code doesn't compile as you haven't included `GetArrayFromColumns`.  [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of you problem I came up with this solution:

```
' Input Array
Dim arr(2) As String
arr(0) = "Tom | Kevin"
arr(1) = "Peter"
arr(2) = "Chris | Katy | Mary"

' Delimitor
Dim del As String
del = " | "

' Array containing Names as single objects
Dim names_array() As Variant

Dim number_of_elements As Integer
number_of_elements = 0

' Loop through all elements of the imput array
For i = 0 To (UBound(arr))
    ' Extract names sperated by del in original String (one element of imput array)
    Dim temp_names() As String
    temp_names = Split(arr(i), del)

    ' Keep track of the number of elements
    number_of_elements = number_of_elements + UBound(temp_names) + 1

    ' Add each name of the current input array object to names_array
    For j = 0 To (UBound(temp_names))
        Dim temp As Integer
        ' Some fancy math to get the number of preserved elements right (can probably be done better)
        temp = number_of_elements - (UBound(temp_names) + 1 - j)
        ReDim Preserve names_array(0 To temp) As Variant
        names_array(UBound(names_array)) = temp_names(j)
    Next j
Next i

' Now names_array should contain all names as individual objects in the array
```

However I am just assuming that you input looks like it does. (Also small disclaimer: I haven't done much in VBA for a long time, so some stuff might look rather sketchy)